# \code{\link{<>}} does not create hyperlink when using roxygen

Tags: r, hyperlink, roxygen

I'm new to Roxygen and using Roxygen to document my functions and scripts (I'm not building a package, but using the package structure in order to be able to use Roxygen). I use `Rd2HTML` function to translate .Rd to .html. I'm trying to make a hyperlink in one .Rd file to another .Rd file, and maintain that link in the .html file.

Suppose I have two scripts and .Rd files: `code1` and `code2`. When I add `\code{\link{code1}}` to the roxygen comments of `code2`, run `roxygenize("<location of package>")` and use `Rd2HTML` to built a html file, the result is that the html-file shows `code1` instead of [code1](http://code1) at the location of `\code{\link{code1}}`. In other words: no hyperlink is shown in the html file of code1, instead `code1` formatted as code is returned. Adding the package name does not resolve the issue.

Can anyone explain this behavior (and solve my issue :))?

Details:
NAMESPACE file:

```
# Generated by roxygen2 (4.1.1): do not edit by hand

export(code1)
export(code2)
```

DESCRIPTION file:

```
Package: Scripts
Type: Package
Title: What the package does (short line)
Version: 0.0.1
Date: 2012-11-12
Author: Who wrote it
Maintainer: Who to complain to <yourfault@somewhere.net>
Description: More about what it does (maybe more than one line)
License: GPL
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue myself. I hadn't installed the package and therefore couldn't locate any .html links.

By the way, http://yihui.name/en/2012/10/build-static-html-help/ helped me to easily build .html pages for help pages.